Why does navigation.navigate suggest params for other screens in React Navigation?
I'm using React Navigation with TypeScript in a React Native app. I've set up type definitions for my navigation stack like this:
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};

Here’s a simplified version of my navigation setup:
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createNativeStackNavigator,
  NativeStackScreenProps,
} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};

type HomeScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;

function HomeScreen({navigation}: HomeScreenProps) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Profile', {userId: 'jane'});
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

type ProfileProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;

function Profile({route, navigation}: ProfileProps) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{route.params.userId}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Feed"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Feed', {sort: 'latest'});
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

When I use navigation.navigate and pass params, the TypeScript intellisense seems to suggest params for all screens, not just the one I’m navigating to. For example:
navigation.navigate('Profile', {userId: 'jane'});

screenshot of VS Code suggesting all props
If I press Ctrl + Space inside the params object, it shows suggestions for userId (which is correct) but also for sort (which belongs to the Feed screen). If I add sort here, TypeScript then complains that it's invalid. It knows it's wrong, but it still suggested it in the first place.
My Question
Is this behavior expected?
Is there a way to make TypeScript intellisense only suggest the correct params for the chosen screen?
Any insights would be appreciated!
